# Setting up websockets server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, em-websocket

this is my first time using websockets and I am having trouble getting my server to work. Below is the simple `em-websocket` server I copied from [this github page](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket). It's basically unchanged right now so it looks like so:

```
require 'em-websocket'

EM.run {
  EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen { |handshake|
    puts "WebSocket connection open"

    # Access properties on the EM::WebSocket::Handshake object, e.g.
    # path, query_string, origin, headers

    # Publish message to the client
    ws.send "Hello Client, you connected to #{handshake.path}"
  }

  ws.onclose { puts "Connection closed" }

  ws.onmessage { |msg|
    puts "Recieved message: #{msg}"
    ws.send("Pong: #{msg}")
  }
end
}
```

I then copied the `html` from [this simple echo test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), just changing the url from `ws://echo.websocket.org` to `ws://localhost:3000/websocket.rb` (the .rb file is located in the `app` directory of my Rails project).

When I run the test from that page, I get the following results:

```
CONNECTED

SENT: WebSocket rocks

RESPONSE: [["client_connected",{"id":null,"channel":null,"data":{"connection_id":70297110490160},"success":null,"result":null,"server_token":null}]]

DISCONNECTED
```

Since the data in this test is hard-coded, I had expected the `SENT` and `RESPONSE` messages to be the same. However, I get the confusing message that begins with `client_connected` but contains nothing but `null` data.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Am I connecting to my "server" (the `websockets.rb` file) and if so do I simply need to make some adjustments in the code, such as create a `reply` method? Again, this is my first time attempting to use this technology so I apologize if I'm missing anything in this post.

For good measure, here is the code that is running in the `echo` test.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:3000/websocket.rb"; 
var output;  
function init() { 
    output = document.getElementById("output"); 
    testWebSocket(); 
}  
function testWebSocket() { 
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { 
        onOpen(evt) 
}; 
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { 
    onClose(evt) 
}; 
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { 
    onMessage(evt) 
}; 
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { 
    onError(evt) }; 
}  
function onOpen(evt) { 
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED"); 
    doSend("WebSocket rocks"); 
}  
function onClose(evt) { 
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED"); 
}  
function onMessage(evt) { 
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>'); 
    websocket.close(); 
}  
function onError(evt) { 
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data); 
}  
function doSend(message) { 
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);  websocket.send(message); 
}  
function writeToScreen(message) { 
    var pre = document.createElement("p"); 
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word"; 
    pre.innerHTML = message; output.appendChild(pre); 
}  
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);  
</script>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>  
<div id="output"></div>  
</html>
```